# Possible to use CLI to remove first bytes from a file until keyword/hex values are found (instead of n bytes/blocks)?

Tags: batch-file, hex, command-line-interface, dd

Long story short, I work with obscure file formats as a hobby. As you can imagine, that often means hex editing. Right now I have a bunch of files which are one format contained within a fake format that just adds some extra header info at the start of the file. 'Converting' them to the more standard format by removing the header makes them readable by standard software. For a while now I've been using dd for this kind of thing, e.g.

```
dd.exe if=%1 of="%~dpn1.head" bs=16 count=35
```

This copies the header into a separate file so I can restore it later using cat in another batch file. (Yes, I'm using Windows binaries of a Linux utilities.)

Trouble is, in this case the main file header isn't always the same number of bytes into each file. At best I'd have to create some kind of filter to check specific filenames to get the right offset, which is a pain and sort of defeats the purpose of turning this into a batch process.

It'd be *excellent* if there was a way to get the position of the main file header and skip to that location procedurally. Obviously this can be done in a GUI hex editor, but for automation and portability's sake I much prefer CLI solutions. Is this possible using dd or a similar utility?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, software library, or other off-site resource are off-topic here. Whilst you've described the problem, we expect you to have tried _and failed_ to solve it before asking. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49248655/edit) to explain what has been done so far to and show us the failing code you would like us to help you with.

Comment: In the post is an example and description of what I have tried. I've also done Google searches and read articles on usage of dd, but I have nothing to show for it since I came up empty-handed (hence why I'm asking here).

dd is what I'm using now, but I don't feel it makes the post off-topic to state I'm open to alternative utilities if the answer to the first question ("is this possible using dd") is "no". I'm asking for solutions regardless of form, not recommendations.